# Redirecting to View Component page ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I recently changed my `WorkShift` view page into a view component. However, I now couldn't go into the view component now with my button. What should be in my `asp-action` for me to go to my view component?

My new view component is in Views->Home->Components->WorkShift->Default.cshtml

How should my button in my view page look like for me to go into the view component page?

View:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <a asp-action="WorkShift" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"><i class=" fa fa-table"></i>Back to List</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask controller action to return ViewComponent.Here is a demo worked:

HomeController:

```
public IActionResult TestButton()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult ReturnViewComponent() {
        List<notes> list = new List<notes> { new notes { Id = "1", Notes = "note1", LastModifedDate = "2020/01/01", LastModifiedBy = "Joy" }, new notes { Id = "2", Notes = "note2", LastModifedDate = "2020/01/02", LastModifiedBy = "Tommy" }, new notes { Id = "3", Notes = "note3", LastModifedDate = "2020/01/03", LastModifiedBy = "Jay" } };
        return ViewComponent("Notes", list);
    }
```

ViewComponents/Notes.cs:

```
public class Notes:ViewComponent
    {
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(List<notes> list)
        {
            return View(list);
        }
    }
```

ViewComponent Location:
Views/Home/Components/Notes/default.cshtml

Views/Home/TestButton.cshtml:

```
<h1>TestButton</h1>
<div>
    <a asp-action="ReturnViewComponent" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"><i class=" fa fa-table"></i>Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: What if I got multiple view components? How do I go into a specific view component

Comment: For example I have 2 view component location: Views/Home/Components/Notes/default.cshtml and Views/Home/Components/Author/default.cshtml. How do i redirect to the author page

Comment: I have edited my answer,If you have Notes component,you need to write ViewComponents/Notes.cs liking in my answer.And use `return ViewComponent("Notes", list);` in controller.If you have Author,you can write a ViewComponents/Author.cs and  `return ViewComponent("Author", list);` in controller.

Comment: @YiyiYou Can you kindly please check this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75777025/how-to-download-the-coverted-doc-file-from-viewcomponent